# count total vowels or consonants in a string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question: Write a function letter_count() that will take in a list or tuple of strings and a string state and return the number of letters that satisfy the string state.

```
      def lettercount(strings, state) :
        if type(strings) != list and type(strings) != tuple :
            raise TypeError("First input is not a list or a tuple")
        if type(state) != str :
            raise TypeError("String state strmust be a string!")
        if state != "vowels" and state != "consonants" :
            raise ValueError("String state str may only be ‘vowels’ or ‘consonants’.")
        vowels = "aeiou"
        letters = ""
        if len(strings) == 0 :
            return 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(strings) :
            if type(strings[i]) != str :
                raise InterruptedError("{} is not a string!".format(strings[i]))
            letters += strings[i]
            i += 1
        counter = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(letters) :
            j = 0
            while j < len(vowels) :
                if type(state) == "vowels" :
                    if letters[i].lower() == vowels[j] :
                        counter += 1
                if type(state) == "consonants" :
                    counter= i+1
                j += 1
            i += 1
        return counter
    print(letter_count(['hello','my','name','is','V@#$'], 'vowels')) #5
    print(letter_count(['asdf'], 'consonants')) #3
    print(letter_count([], 'vowels')) #0
    print(letter_count(['qwe#$%'], 'consonants')) #2
```

I don't understand why consonants can't be calculated. Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

checking like this will always return false

```
if type(state) == "vowels" :
```

and

```
if type(state) == "consonants" :
```

will return str, you just need to check like this

```
if state == "vowels" :
```

and

```
if state == "consonants" :
```

I have modified your code a bit to return the result you expected

```
def letter_count(strings, state):
    if type(strings) != list and type(strings) != tuple :
        raise TypeError("First input is not a list or a tuple")
    if type(state) != str :
        raise TypeError("String state strmust be a string!")
    if state != "vowels" and state != "consonants" :
        raise ValueError("String state str may only be vowels or consonants.")
    vowels = "aeiou"
    letters = ""
    if len(strings) == 0 :
        return 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(strings) :
        if type(strings[i]) != str :
            raise InterruptedError("{} is not a string!".format(strings[i]))
        letters += strings[i]
        i += 1
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(letters) :
        if state == "vowels" :
            if letters[i].lower() in vowels:
                counter += 1
        if state == "consonants" :
            if letters[i].lower() not in vowels and letters[i].isalnum():
                counter += 1
        i += 1
    return counter
print(letter_count(['hello','my','name','is','V@#$'], 'vowels')) #5
print(letter_count(['asdf'], 'consonants')) #3
print(letter_count([], 'vowels')) #0
print(letter_count(['qwe#$%'], 'consonants')) #2
```

output

```
5
3
0
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        j = 0
        while j < len(vowels) :
            if type(state) == "vowels" :
                if letters[i].lower() == vowels[j] :
```

Should be

```
        if letters[i].lower() in vowels:
```